# How to convert Birth date to age ( years, months, days ) and age( years, months, days ) to birth date conversion in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a form where the user can input a patient age in years, months and days. That will save the data in the database according to the patient's date of birth. The problem is I'm using **strtotime()** function to get the DOB of the patient, but when I want to show the age (years, months, days) from retrieving the date form the birthday column, sometimes it showing 1 or 2 days (+-) result. I'm using **date_diff()** function to retrieving the age (years, months, days). Any solution for my problem ?

```php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$dateOfBirth = strtotime("$today -2 years -2 months -20 days");
$birthday = date("Y-m-d", $dateOfBirth);

//and then tried to retrieve the age from that date which give me wrong answer

$diff = date_diff(date_create($birthday), date_create($today));

echo $diff->y; // showing 2
echo $diff->m; // showing 2
echo $diff->d; // showing 22 (it should be 20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the following line in your code to this:

```
$diff = date_diff(date_create($today), date_create($birthday));
```

Test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9dece465739e2315be32b7882ba3ca9a5d9d65b3

Answer (score 0):

I hope you doing well, i read your question and found the following solution based on my research and my knowledge.

I hope this will helps you to resolve your problem.

=>To get the total year based on birthrate you can use the following code.

```
$bday = new DateTime('10.01.2001'); // Your date of birth
$today = new Datetime(date('m.d.y'));
$diff = $today->diff($bday);
printf(' Your age : %d years, %d month, %d days', $diff->y, $diff->m, $diff->d); //You will get your age
```

You can copy and paste the code in [Fiddle](https://phpfiddle.org) to test the output.
Using this you will definitely got your age by birth date.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple function `Calc_Age()` to calculate this, it's very accurate and precise and I hope it's what you are looking for... below my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Patient Age Information</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  function Calc_Age($myday) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
    $birth = new DateTime($myday);
    $birth->format('Y-m-d');
    $today = new DateTime('NOW');
    $today->format('Y-m-d');
    $diffs = $today->diff($birth);
    $myage = $diffs->y . ($diffs->y == 1 ? ' year, ' : ' years, ');
    $myage .= $diffs->m . ($diffs->m == 1 ? ' month and ' : ' months and ');
    $myage .= $diffs->d . ($diffs->d == 1 ? ' day' : ' days');
    return $myage;
  }
?>



<h1>Patient: Angela Bennet</h1>

<p>Angela Bennet is <?php echo Calc_Age("1967-01-23"); ?> old</p>

<h1>Patient: Jhon Malkovich</h1>

<p>Jhon Malkovich is <?php echo Calc_Age("1977-04-14"); ?> old</p>

</body>

</html>
```

### Result:

[image: Patient Age Information]

I hope this helps.